# Filter only post method request with a specific parameter name

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

How do I filter requests with a specific parameter: e.g. filter only request with "csrf-token" parameter name. The filter will first check if the request has the required parameter name and bypass those *without* the required parameter.

Below is how I setup my *web.xml* file but the problem is that all requests are filtered:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFTest</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.example.CSRFFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>csrf_token</param-name>
        <param-value>csrf</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFTest</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CrossSiteScriptStripper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CrossSiteScriptStripperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Apply the CrossSiteScriptStripper filter to all servlets and JSP pages. -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CrossSiteScriptStripper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The answers given by pb2q is working on my **TEST PROJECT** but I'm getting an error when inserted on my real project. I would like to ask if its possible to use 2 filters?

Comment: One way may be inside Filter class omit all requests from filter chain  by doing if/else?

Comment: @Jhays you can chain as many filters as you need, what error do you get on your real project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Filter` class will receive a `ServletRequest` in its [`doFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29) method: this is analogous to a regular servlet's `service` method (or `doGet`, `doPost`, for `HTTPServlet`).

In your `doFilter` method, check the request for the required parameter using `ServletRequest.getParameter`: if the parameter *doesn't* exist, the method will return `null`.

If the parameter doesn't exist then block the request: don't pass it back into the filter chain using `FilterChain.doFilter`.

Pseudocode:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                     FilterChain chain)
{
    // ...

    if (req.getParameter(MY_PARAMNAME) != null)
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    // otherwise don't call doFilter

    // ...
}
```

I'm not sure what you're expecting to do with the params in your config file, but if you want to specify *which* HTTP query parameter is required in the request, you might use this config/code combo:

```
<param-name>required_parameter_name</param-name>
<param-value>csrf-token</param-value>
```

Then in your `init` method:

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
{
    // ...

    // use this value in your doFilter method, in place of MY_PARAMNAME, above
    this.requiredParameterName =
        filterConfig.getInitParameter("required_parameter_name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much pb2q. Its now working fine, just have to add landing page for those successfully filtered and a warning for invalid request.